# Why does Active Directory work with Visual Studio MVC templates when using IIS Express but not Kestrel?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, kestrel-http-server

I see my AD name when I use IIS Express is

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

I switch to Kestrel and the name is blank ?

What happened to AD with Kestrel?

I've tried some fixes below but not quite sure I knew what I was doing

```
services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

 //.UseHttpSys(options =>
                //{
                //    options.Authentication.Schemes =
                //        AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM |
                //        AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                //    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                //})
```

Answer (score 1):

As documentation states in [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth):

> Windows Authentication (also known as Negotiate, Kerberos, or NTLM
>   authentication) can be configured for ASP.NET Core apps hosted with
>   [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index) or [HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys).

**So `Kestrel` just simply doesn't support `Windows Authentication`.** You have two options: to host with [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index) or [HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys). Tu use 'HTTP.sys' you need this:

```
.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
})
```

Comment: How does this relate to the settings in launchSettings.json  ?  I always thought the option were just IIS or Kestrel.

Comment: This site can’t be reached The connection was reset. When I made the 2 changes needed for HTTP.SYS :(

Comment: @punkouter I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This may not help you now, but Windows Authentication with Kestrel (including on Linux and Mac) will be supported in ASP.NET Core 3, which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).

Comment: We will upgrade to v3 before its released so hopefully this makes my problem go away .. In the end we will use docker and I guess want to host in Kestral anyways